# How do I substitute $w=-1$ and $z=\infty$ in my equation?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I am given $w=-1$ and $z=\infty$.

I also know that $\frac{1}{\infty} =0$.

How do I substitute the value of $z$ and $w$ in
$$w=\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}$$
without complicating the equation?

Comment: Divide top and bottom by $z$, and then take the limit as $|z|\to\infty$. If we are told that this limit is $-1$, then $\frac{a}{c}=-1$. The only exception is the trivial case $a=c=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean how do I let $z$ approach infinity and $w=-1$ to get a simplified equation. Factor the $z$ on the top and bottom to get:

$$w=\frac{a+\frac{b}{z}}{c+\frac{d}{z}}$$

Now let $z \to \infty$

To get

$$w=\frac{a}{c}=-1$$

However Like Andre said, if we have $a=c=0$, then the equation is independent of $a$ and $c$, and it reduces to:

$$w=\frac{b}{d}=-1$$

Comment: How did you just move z from a?

Comment: I multiplied top and bottom by (1/z)

Comment: $az(1/z)=a$ likewise $cz(1/z)=c$

Comment: You cleared my doubt. Thanks.